# How many lost continents are in Mythology?

Tags: greek, comparative, egyptian, atlantis

A majority of people will know of Atlantis. It is a Greek, fictional island, misregarded as oral history. Atlantis is mentioned in Plato's works Timaeus and Critias and is placed in the Atlantic Ocean.

Then, I recently learned of Mu. Mu was thought to be located in the Atlantic Ocean. It was believed to belong to the Egyptians and Mesoamericans before Mu was lost.

I thought lost continents were only in Greek stories, but if you find it somewhere else, it will be in more.

Which cultures/mythologies have a lost continent/advanced civilization story?

Comment: I wonder if [Cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult)s qualify....

Comment: I read the link you provided, but I don't really understand it. Could you dumb it down for me?

Comment: Thule, Hyperborea, Lemuria, Mu are names perhaps worth a quick look.

Comment: @sand1 [Mu](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(lost_continent)) is based on a delusional 19th century mistranslation of Mayan writings.